# Resizing Nivo Slider Issues

Tags: css, nivo-slider

I'm having issues with my NIVO slider:

http://rusticblonde.hostizzo.com/

I've managed to resize the box and when the image loads, however when it changes the changing image is still small.

Any ideas where I need to amend the height to resolve this?

Also it appears to create a scrollbar when I've wrapped it in the page wrapper.

Is it the case that the NIVO slider resizes itself to the width and height of the DIV that its contained in? If so I think I will edit this.

Comment: Can you describe the problem more clearly? As an aside, you have `<div id="pagewrap">` as the very first line of your HTML, something's gone wrong there.

Comment: Hi Basically im trying to resize the size of the nivo slider. Im wrapping it in one complete wrapper u see :)

Comment: There's quite a few pieces of broken html code on your page. If you tidy all of that up it may help somewhat. use this: http://validator.w3.org/

Comment: hi Billy, no worries i will try this... i dont understand how its got broken :S